# Why is there no open-collector OR-gate in the 7400 series?

Tags: logic-gates, open-collector, 7400

I searched in the "List of 7400 series integrated circuits" on Wikipedia for a open-collector OR-gate, but couldn't find any.

The list looks complete, so I assume there is no such chip in the 7400 series.

Why is there no open-collector OR-gate in the 7400 series?

Comment: There was never sufficient commercial demand to create such a special-purpose part.

Comment: As @DaveTweed said there is very little demand.  Open-collector parts are only used rarely - they are mainly for interfacing to non-logic gates.   OR gates are also not used very much - in 40 years of designing digital circuitry I have never designed them in. The combination of the two is more rarely required.

Comment: An application of open-collector gates was driving a  bus structure, where an idle bus was pulled high by resistors.  NANDs have an advantage over NORs, because one input is used as **enable** while the other input is used as **data**.  *Tri-state*  bus buffers were introduced later.

Comment: Only the people that created the 7400 series eons ago could answer this.  Everyone else is just guessing at reasons they *might* have made the decisions they did.  Closing this pointless opinion-based question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't genuinely know the answer to your question, but I can speculate that it's because there *are* (quad) open-collector NAND and NOR gates, which are universal gates, and you can relatively easily synthesize an open collector OR gate from these. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZPwmE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because, of course, `A NOR 0 = ~A` and `~(A NOR B) = A OR B`